# How to filter records which includes open intervals or specific closed intervals with Oracle SQL WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I use an oracle database and I have the following database tables (the Date format is only dd.MM.yyyy):

```
ID | ACCOUNT_ID    |    BEGINN_DATE     |     END_DATE      |     NO_END_DATE_AVAILABE    |     MAX_END_DATE_QUARTER    |    QUARTER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |      1        |    01.10.2019      |     31.12.2019    |              0              |          31.12.2019         |   01.10.2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2 |      1        |    01.01.2020      |     04.01.2020    |              0              |          04.01.2020         |   01.01.2020
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3 |      1        |    05.01.2020      |        NULL       |              1              |          04.01.2020         |   01.01.2020
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4 |      2        |    02.11.2019      |     10.01.2020    |              0              |          25.02.2020         |   01.10.2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5 |      2        |    02.11.2019      |     10.01.2010    |              0              |          25.02.2020         |   01.01.2020
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 6 |      2        |    11.01.2020      |     25.02.2020    |              0              |          25.02.2020         |   01.01.2020
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 7 |      3        |    02.07.2019      |     25.08.2019    |              0              |          30.09.2019         |   01.07.2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 8 |      3        |    26.08.2019      |     15.09.2019    |              0              |          30.09.2019         |   01.07.2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9 |      3        |    16.09.2019      |     30.09.2019    |              0              |          30.09.2019         |   01.07.2019  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10 |      3        |    01.10.2019      |     15.10.2019    |              0              |          15.10.2019         |   01.10.2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11 |      3        |    16.10.2019      |        NULL       |              1              |          15.10.2019         |   01.10.2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12 |      4        |    29.09.2019      |     02.10.2019    |              0              |          02.10.2019         |   01.07.2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
13 |      4        |    29.09.2019      |     02.10.2019    |              0              |          02.10.2019         |   01.10.2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14 |      4        |    03.10.2019      |        NULL       |              1              |          02.10.2019         |   01.10.2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The column **BEGINN_DATE** and **END_DATE** represent an interval of date values. The values inside the column **quarter** represent only the first day of the quarter, which is included by value between the columns **BEGINN_DATE** and **END_DATE**.

I would like to describe how kind of tuple I want to filter from this database table.

**For each Quarter** I want to get

- the record where inside the column END_DATE it exists a **NULL** value
- the record where the value of the column represent the **MAX Date** of this quarter

Further down I have mentioned some examples, which I want to filter from my database table.

I want to get these records for **Account_ID 1**:

```
ID | ACCOUNT_ID    |    BEGINN_DATE     |     END_DATE      |     NO_END_DATE_AVAILABE    |       MAX_END_DATE_QUARTER    |    QUARTER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |      1        |    01.10.2019      |     31.12.2019    |              0              |            31.12.2019         |   01.10.2019
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3 |      1        |    05.01.2020      |        NULL       |              1              |            04.01.2020         |   01.01.2020
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get these records for **Account_ID 2**:

```
ID | ACCOUNT_ID    |    BEGINN_DATE     |     END_DATE      |     NO_END_DATE_AVAILABE    |       MAX_END_DATE_QUARTER    |    QUARTER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4 |      2        |    02.11.2019      |     10.01.2020    |              0              |            25.02.2020         |   01.10.2019
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
 6 |      2        |    11.01.2020      |     25.02.2020    |              1              |            25.02.2020         |   01.01.2020
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get these records for **Account_ID 3**:

```
ID | ACCOUNT_ID    |    BEGINN_DATE     |     END_DATE      |     NO_END_DATE_AVAILABE    |      MAX_END_DATE_QUARTER     |    QUARTER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9 |      3        |    16.09.2019      |     30.09.2019    |              0              |            30.09.2019         |   01.07.2019  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11 |      3        |    16.10.2019      |        NULL       |              1              |            15.10.2019         |   01.10.2019
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get these records for **Account_ID 4**:

```
ID | ACCOUNT_ID    |    BEGINN_DATE     |     END_DATE      |     NO_END_DATE_AVAILABE    |      MAX_END_DATE_QUARTER     |    QUARTER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12 |      4        |    29.09.2019      |     02.10.2019    |              0              |            02.10.2019         |   01.07.2019
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14 |      4        |    03.10.2019      |        NULL       |              1              |            02.10.2019         |   01.10.2019
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have written a SQL WHERE clause something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable t
WHERE (t.no_end_date_available = 1 AND t.end_date IS NULL) OR
      (t.no_end_date_available = 0 AND t.end_date = t.max_end_date_quarter)
```

But this SQL WHERE doesn´t working fine. For **Account_ID 1** I get these records:

```
ID | ACCOUNT_ID    |    BEGINN_DATE     |     END_DATE      |     NO_END_DATE_AVAILABE    |     MAX_END_DATE_QUARTER    |    QUARTER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |      1        |    01.10.2019      |     31.12.2019    |              0              |          31.12.2019         |   01.10.2019
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2 |      1        |    01.01.2020      |     04.01.2020    |              0              |          04.01.2020         |   01.01.2020
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3 |      1        |    05.01.2020      |        NULL       |              1              |          04.01.2020         |   01.01.2020
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But I want to get these records:

```
ID | ACCOUNT_ID    |    BEGINN_DATE     |     END_DATE      |     NO_END_DATE_AVAILABE    |       MAX_END_DATE_QUARTER    |    QUARTER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |      1        |    01.10.2019      |     31.12.2019    |              0              |            31.12.2019         |   01.10.2019
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3 |      1        |    05.01.2020      |        NULL       |              1              |            04.01.2020         |   01.01.2020
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I solve this problem? Many thanks for helping me.

Comment: why don't you want the 2nd record for Account 1? It seems to fit your requirement that the end date = max_end_date_quarter.  Your date format seems to switch between DD.MM.YYYY and MM.DD.YYYY

Comment: Why do you even need the NO_END_DATE_AVAILABLE column?  The very fact that the END_DATE tests as NULL indicates exactly the same thing, and without the possibility of a mis-match.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `BEGINN_DATE` and `END_DATE` columns, `date` or `varchar2`, or something else?

Comment: I rolled back your last edit where you removed all the essential parts of your question. A question with "*I have the following database tables*" and then nothing else, doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query might help you get what you are looking for:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT m.id, 
             m.account_id, 
             m.begin_date,
             m.end_date, 
             m.quarter, 
             MAX(NVL(m.end_date, to_date('31.12.3000', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))) OVER (PARTITION BY m.account_id, m.quarter) AS MAX_DATE
      FROM myTable m) sub
WHERE DECODE(sub.end_date, NULL, 1, sub.max_date, 1, 0) = 1;
```

I'm effectively recalculating your MAX_END_DATE_QUARTER to ensure that NULLs are always the max value by putting a false super high date in as the max.  Then the outer query only selects NULL end dates or ones where the end date matches the calculated max.

The following SQLFiddle shows this query with the provided test data. ([Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf25e8/1/0))

Comment: sorry, but your solution doesn´t work. I always get a NULL value and the highest MAX Date inside a quarter. The same problem, which I have described on top.

Comment: @Ben I'm not seeing your results.  I've added a SQLFiddle to the answer to show you that I'm getting the expected results.  Are you storing your dates as `CHAR`? I assumed they were dates.

Comment: Could it be a problem, if I use Oracle 10 or 12?

Comment: @Ben  I don’t think so. The only thing I can think of is that the `TO…DATE` function value wasn’t high enough. Try 31.12.9999, I probably should have used it anyway. Want to avoid the brain trying to type 2000 out of habit.  Also, is it possible that there are other columns that you didn’t show in the question which could affect the `PARTITION BY`?

Comment: It could be possible, that some other columns manipulate the final result. During the last days I haven´t found some free time to solve this problem. I try to fix it during the next days